# Computing homology class of curve in product of elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties, computer-algebra

I have a smooth, projective curve $X/\mathbb{C}$ of genus $g$, embedded in a product of elliptic curves $A = \prod_{i=1}^g E_i$. Since $H_*(A; \mathbb{Z})$ with the Pontryagin product is isomorphic to the exterior algebra $\Lambda(H_1(A; \mathbb{Z})) \cong \Lambda(\mathbb{Z}^{2g})$, given a basis $a_1, \dots, a_{2g}$ for $H_1(A; \mathbb{Z})$, we get a basis $\{a_i \wedge a_j : 1 \leq i < j \leq 2g\}$ for $H_2(A; \mathbb{Z})$. Is there a practical algorithm that computes the fundamental class $[X] \in H_2(A; \mathbb{Z})$ in terms of this basis, given defining equations for $X$ and each $E_i$? If so, has it been implemented in computer algebra software like Sage, Magma, Macaulay2, etc.?

(For broader context, my actual goal is to compute the degree of the induced map $\operatorname{Jac}(X) \to A$, which I've already proven is an isogeny in my case. If I can compute the fundamental class $[X] \in H_2(A; \mathbb{Z})$, then I can extract the degree of this isogeny from the value of the power $[X]^g$ under the Pontryagin product.)